# openMP VS2017 doesn't work

Tags: c++, openmp

When I try to use openMP with my VS 2017 c++ program, I go to

Properties -> C/C++ -> Allow OpenMP (or something like this) : YES.

But then, I go to my main, and write only :

```
void main(){
   #pragma omp parallel for
   for (int n = 0; n<10; ++n)
   {
        printf(" %d", n);
   }
   printf(".\n");
 }
```

as in the example found [here](https://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/) .

The expected results is (in the example) :   0 5 6 7 1 8 2 3 4 9.
meaning that parallelism is used.
In my case, it prints 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9. everytime, (even when I use `#pragma omp parallel num_threads(8)`) meaning that no parallelism is used. Is there something i'm missing?

Comment: No, this was only a partial answer... in fact this was only for the first "question", the second question is still there. I will try to explain it better... Sorry

Comment: What if you use `#pragma omp parallel num_threads(8)`?

Comment: Did it too :  still the same :/
tried `#pragma omp parallel num_threads(8)
 {
 #pragma omp for
  {
   for (int n = 0; n < 10; ++n) printf(" %d", n);
  }
 }
` as it is mentionned in the link I gave

Comment: @RaphSchim the result doesn't mean OpenMP isn't working - thousands of devs would have noticed several years ago. It probably means that 10 is so tiny a number that parallel execution and *synchronization* in order to access the console would cost way more than running everything on a single core. Try with a realistic value. And/or add some actual processing, like calculating a square. In this case you are trying to access the console through multiple cores that do nothing. The compiler could easily optimize this away because there's no parallel code at all

Comment: Ok : I used that : `#pragma omp parallel num_threads(8)
 {
 #pragma omp for
  {
   for (int n = 0; n < 100000; ++n)
   {
    float f = sqrt(n) + sqrt(pow(n, 5)) / sqrt(n % 35);
     
    printf("%d %f\n", n, f);
   }
  }
 }`
It is still done sequentially

Comment: Well, I tried to create another project; I did exactly the same as before and now it works. I do'nt really understand...

Answer (score 1):

The leading bracket `{` cannot be on the `#pragma omp parallel` line, which is a preprocessor directive. Use

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
   std::cout << "Hello World\n";
}
```

instead.

---

Note that without this syntax, the program would be invalid when compiled without OpenMP support (ignored `#pragma omp` directives).

Comment: Yes! It was a part of my problem! But my real problem is that openMP isn't supported even with the right syntax ... It was the second part of my problem :/

Comment: @RaphSchim the real problem is that your code doesn't execute anything in parallel and the loop is tiny. Try with realistic code and values

Comment: As i mentionned in the other comment, I tried something else. And at the begginning, my for loop was about to take a photo (differents for each loop) and do some stuff on them then save them. Since it didn't work, I tried to create minimal example to see where the problem was. But it seems that even with minimal code, it doesn't work